# How can I use *.* in the Windows 7 search filter?

Tags: windows-7, windows-search, wildcards

Why in the world can I not use `*.*` in Windows 7 search? All I want to do is return all the files in all the sub-directories in one location so I can sort by dimensions. Any one know how to return all files in a Windows search?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try searching for **~*** in the directory that you want to search.

The Tilde (~) lets you use the old DOS search syntax. The asterisk (*) means "return everything".

You could also use **type:NOT"file folder"** which would exclude the listing of all the folders but show all files.

Some sources for advanced query syntax:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/technicalresources/advquery.mspx

Comment: Awesome, the ~* worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @perlox Hi perlox. Glad I could help! Please mark the answer with a check mark to indicate that your question has been answered.

Comment: Oops sorry, almost forgot. Thanks for the reminder :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure just a `!` will return everything in a given folder you're searching from.

Comment: You should verify your answer.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for, but I assure you that I tested (and researched to confirm) before posting the answer. Shall I provide screenshots? Is there an issue you've found with this approach?